# how can I generate a list of days by known months

Tags: python, list, datetime

I just start learning python for few weeks and now have a problem with datetimes

I generate a list like this

```
datetime.date(1991, 11, 1),
datetime.date(1991, 12, 1),
datetime.date(1992, 1, 1),
...
datetime.date(2017, 10, 1),
datetime.date(2017, 11, 1),
datetime.date(2017, 12, 1)]
```

which the time step is month
and I would like to use it to create a list like this

```
datetime.date(1991, 11, 1),
datetime.date(1991, 11, 2),
datetime.date(1991, 11, 3),
...
datetime.date(2017, 12, 29),
datetime.date(2017, 12, 30),
datetime.date(2017, 12, 31)]
```

which the time step become days and the last day is the end of the month.

I use some way such as calculate monthrange and then generate a new list from the starting day, but the code seems lengthy and not so good.

Do anyone have a better way to solve this? thanks for advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would probably be to have a generator with a configurable step.

```
from datetime import date, timedelta

def days(start, end, step=timedelta(days=1)):
    curr = start
    while curr <= end:
        yield curr
        curr += step

print(list(days(date(2017, 1, 1), date(2017, 1, 3))))
# [datetime.date(2017, 1, 1), datetime.date(2017, 1, 2), datetime.date(2017, 1, 3)]
```

Comment: super ! one more queation, because the original list is created by a "def" as well, so the time imformation is always the first day of that month. How can I  use this def but handle the variable "end" with the first day of month?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  If you already have the month and year, then the first day of that month is just `date(year, month, 1)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "timedelta" module from a starting date as follows:

```
from datetime import datetime,timedelta

startDate = datetime(1991,1,1)
endDate = datetime(2017,12,31)

oneDayDelta = timedelta(days=1)

totalDaysOfInterest = (endDate - startDate).days

myDatesList = [startDate + k*oneDayDelta for k in range(totalDaysOfInterest)]
```